# Struts action halts for first form submission

Tags: struts2, tomcat8

Whenever i restart my tomcat and submit my form it executes properly, but when i do same thing simultaneously with 2 browsers, my application halts until my first request is completed its execution.

I am confused is this tomcat issue or struts?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can deploy your application on another  web server, what it's doing so hard that it halts on the first request? May be you have deadlocks. Clarify the problem so it could have a solution possibility.

Comment: what i m trying to do is submit single form from 2 different browser or system, so when i restart my tomcat and submit the form ,instead of serving 2 requests it is executing first request and once it is done ,then only it allows any other requests to execute.

Comment: Can you add something more detailed explanation, because I've already read this in the question.

Comment: Assume i have 2 mysql queries  query 1:"select sleep(20)" & query 2:"select sleep(5)" to execute from my application.
Now i restart my tomcat and open my application from 2 different systems, as i submit my query1 to execute it starts executing which we can be seen in mysql and after that immediately i submit my query2 to execute, this time i see my form is submitted and reached to action class but it is not reached to execute() method.
Now my query2 is waiting for first query to execute.
This issue comes only when i restart my tomcat and make a request for first time after restart.

Comment: Where did it reach then, how about struts filter? What is the action configuration? How do you use mysql with struts?

Comment: Struts-Filter
<filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


Action-Configuration
<action name="sampleaction" class="com.rummycircle.SampleMain">
 <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
 <result name="success" type="redirect">SampleMainPage.jsp</result>
</action>

Comment: Then it's not struts problem, just mysql problem?

Comment: But it occurs only when i restart tomcat and also it happens for first execution.